# Are DataSource.Connection / DataSource.Provider the way to go to create an OAUTH connection to a 3rd party?

Tags: integration, rest

I've played with JSON.serialize() & .deserialize() to pack & unpack data that I will be sending to a 3rd party (PureCloud).  We have an existing integration with Twilio to send & receive SMS, but their integration has a static token stored in a Custom Setting in Salesforce, vs. the ClientId/ClientSecret to request a token with each request.

The Apex Connector example for google (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_connector_example_google_drive.htm) looks like what I should be working from to actually authenticate, but I can't find an example of the DataSource.ConnectionParams being created/initialized.

I've created a Custom Setting to store the ClientId & ClientSecret -- can someone point me to an example where that DataSource record is populated?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I have both parts now - the JSON object for the data, and HttpRequest for the connection - here's a thread from April that addresses this: [Oauth process for PureCloud/Genesys...](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/216303/oauth-process-for-purecloud-genesys-step-one-retrieving-the-access-token) (and yes, it's a previous question of mine -- can I help it if this project has a 'dynamic priority profile'?!?)

Thanks for your help -- I'll come back & post a follow-up that combines the two into something useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to create an OAuth connection for a custom OData connector, I think you want to be looking at the following Help Page: [Define an External Data Source for Salesforce Connect—Custom Adapter](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=apex_add_external_data_source.htm). It includes links to other documentation with directions on how to configure the OAuth settings. There's also some related information in the Apex docs under [Set Up Salesforce Connect to Use Your Custom Adapter](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.214.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_connector_start_setup.htm?search_text=json).

I'm currently writing an https service myself to authenticate with another service by passing a JWT Bearer token. I have to manually generate the token since it's going *outbound* instead of coming *inbound*. If it were *inbound* and/or Salesforce was serving as the idP, I could configure a connected app to handle everything in the OAuth for me; making it all much easier.

If you're handling all of the authentication yourself, I think you'll want to read [Authentication for Salesforce Connect Custom Adapters](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_connector_authentication.htm) and look at the [Auth Namespace](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_namespace_Auth.htm). Those methods are the ones that will be applicable to what it is that you're doing.